# How to search record using Find in through foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to generics. I am calling a method passing foreign key id to search record from different table. here is my code

```
    public void Get<T>(long id) where T : class
    {
        var userdetails = Db.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
```

Where T could be any table and id is foreign key in T table. I want to search record through foreign key using Find method.Get method is called from places passing different table related with one table with foreign key.

Comment: Find only search record through primary key i know that but i want to search using foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use expression :

```
public void Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    var userdetails = Db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

then you call it like below:

```
repo.Get<MyClass>(x=>x.FieldName == xxxx);
```

Comment: repo.Get<MyClass>(x=>x.Id == xxxx);

Comment: btw, why returning "void" in a "Get" function?
better make it like this: `public T Get<T>(.....) { return Db.Set<T>()......; }`